# registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is not called

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

neither`registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()` is called nor `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` , i dunno why , i tried many solutions but nothing works

code for my PreferenceFragment

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
}
```

SettingsActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mSettingsToolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    mSettingsToolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbarSettings);

    setSupportActionBar(mSettingsToolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id=item.getItemId();
    if(id==android.R.id.home){
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

here is my method to setup sharedPreferenced

```
private void setupSharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    autoplay =  sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.autoplay_checkbox_key),getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.autoplay_checkbox_pref));
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+autoplay,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    onSharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if(key.equals(R.string.autoplay_checkbox_key)){
                autoplay=sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.autoplay_checkbox_pref));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+autoplay,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
}
```

i searched a lot and used many solutions but still the same , so what should i do to make it work ? , is there any better solution to use ?!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it works , i just need to change my method to this

```
 private void setupSharedPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    autoplay =  sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.autoplay_checkbox_key),getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.autoplay_checkbox_pref));

    onSharedPreferenceChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
            if(key==getString(R.string.autoplay_checkbox_key))
                autoplay=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getBoolean(getString(R.string.autoplay_checkbox_key)
                        ,getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.autoplay_checkbox_pref));

        }
    };
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onSharedPreferenceChangeListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can not see your complete codes, but below lines are valid:

```
private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;  //listener is a class field instance

listener= new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {//instantiate listener
      @Override
        public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            //implementation goes here
        }
};
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener); //then register it
```